# Discrepancies in reprojection to British National Grid using different software

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, united-kingdom, bng

I am converting coordinate values from EPSG 4326 (lat long) to EPSG 27700 (British National Grid).  I have used QGIS and am then verifying the results using GDAL, but I am find that for higher latitudes the results do not match:

**Using QGIS**

| Long | Lat | BNG_X | BNG_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3 | 61 | 346015 | 1235698 |
| -4 | 61 | 291937 | 1236937 |

**Using GDAL (gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:27700)**

| Long | Lat | BNG_X | BNG_Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3 | 61 | 345920 | 1235625 |
| -4 | 61 | 291850 | 1236864 |

What is causing this divergence of results at more northern latitudes?

Comment: QGIS is also using the Proj library for coordinate operations. Compare the versions you have. From QGIS you find the information from Help-About.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command from your GDAL shell:

```
projinfo  -s epsg:4326 -t epsg:27700
```

You will probably see at the end of the output

> Grid OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb needed but not found on the system.
> Can be obtained from the proj-datumgrid-europe package at
> https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-europe-latest.zip

Download the grid and place it into the proj data directory, it may be share/proj. After that you should get the same results than from QGIS, that obviously has the datum grid file.

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:27700
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
-3 61
346015.472779439 1235697.68734433 0
```